# SUMPRODUCT formula with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a spreadsheet and trying to get the number of offspring units that produced an amount within a certain range

`more than 4,374 and less than 10,000`

This is what I am using, but am getting `#VALUE`:

```
=IF(ISTEXT([@[Director Status]]),SUMPRODUCT([Unit Whsl. Sales],[Parent Unit],[@Unit],[Unit Whsl. Sales]>4374,[Unit Whsl. Sales]<10000))
```

Answer (score 0):

The #VALUE! error typically comes from attempting to use text values (even text values that look like numbers) in a mathematical operation and SUMPRODUCT() is not very forgiving in this regard. Additionally, your boolean criteria should be isolated with brackets and either converted to numbers with a double unary (e.g. --([Unit Whsl. Sales]>4374)) or multiplied against each other to force conversion from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0.

```
=IF(ISTEXT([@[Director Status]]),SUMPRODUCT([Unit Whsl. Sales],[Parent Unit],[@Unit],([Unit Whsl. Sales]>4374)*([Unit Whsl. Sales]<10000)))
  ... or,
=IF(ISTEXT([@[Director Status]]),SUMPRODUCT([Unit Whsl. Sales],[Parent Unit],[@Unit],--([Unit Whsl. Sales]>4374), --([Unit Whsl. Sales]<10000)))
```

Without sample data it is pretty hard to diagnose but that might be a starting point. Check your columns of numbers for text or text that look like numbers.

Comment: Thanks!  I changed the formula to:  =IF(ISTEXT([@[Director Status]]),SUMPRODUCT([Unit Whsl. Sales],[Parent Unit],[@Unit],--([Unit Whsl. Sales]>4374),--([Unit Whsl. Sales]<10000)),"-") but I am still getting #VALUE.  Here is what I'm looking at where I'm trying to show the # of offspring units that have wholesale sales > 4374 and < 10,000.  The value in the top right cell should be 2. Table coming...

Comment: @Sarah Stewart - Upload redacted sample data to a public file area like OneDrive or Google Drive and post a link to the publically shared workbook back here.